# Python annotation error due to circular dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

I have two classes that are dependent one another and are working fine without annotations.
Unfortunately, when I try and annotate **return values**, it causes an *expected* circular dependency error.

**Network.py**

```
def processors(self) -> List[Processor]:
    # implementation
```

**Processor.py**

```
def network(self) -> Network:
    # implementation
```

How can I annotate without having to use the `import` statement which causes a circular dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [forward reference](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references):

```
def processors(self) -> List['Processor']:
    # implementation
```

Yes, it looks a bit ugly, but it appears to be the intended solution.